# How to ingest using .set-or-append with let statement

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to ingest data into a table by using [.set-or-append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query) and [let statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/letstatement) as well.

So basically I am trying to ingest data using this query:

```
let HexCode = "2";
.set-or-append Test <|
    Test
    | where Column startswith "2"
```

But then I am getting a message error:

> The incomplete fragment is unexpected.

If I add the let statement `let HexCode = "2";` below the `.set-or-append`, it works, but not as expected. It ingested less rows than it should.

I didn't find any syntax about that on the documentation. Am I doing right? How can I ingest using multiple let statements if I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `let` statement is part of the query in the command, and thus should be included after the `<|`.

for example:

```
.set-or-append T2 <|
    let HexCode = "2";
    T1
    | where Column startswith HexCode
```