# How does one specify query parameters when performing an inline ingestion in the Azure Data Explorer Java SDK?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion, adx, kusto-java-sdk

I am trying to perform an inline ingestion into an ADX table (using the Java SDK) and although there is no exception thrown at the time I execute the command, no rows are returned and the ingestion receives an error message:

```
Stream_WrongNumberOfFields: hr: '2161770504' 'CSV error: record 4 (line: 5, byte: 179): found record with 4 fields, but the previous record has 1 fields'
```

Note that the error message comes when trying to ingest into a table that has no records.

I tried initially using the default ingestion policy but then tried adding an explicit policy to see if that helped (it didn't).  I am invoking this via the Java SDK, however, I can demonstrate the error in the web UI.  Here is the kql code I am running:

```
.ingest inline into table MyTable
with (
format = "csv",
ingestionMappingReference = "MyMapping"
) <|
declare query_parameters(field1:string);                                                                                                                                                                     
declare query_parameters(field2:string);                                                                                                                                                                     
declare query_parameters(field3:string);                                                                                                                                                                     
declare query_parameters(timeField:string);                                                                                                                                                                  
[field1, field2, field3, timeField]
```

This statement succeeds if I remove the declare statements, and I am guessing that it is somehow interpreting those lines as part of the inline ingestion (I have tried with and without the square brackets), however I get an error if I move the declare statements earlier in the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*query* parameters, as their name implies, can only be used in *queries*, and not in control commands. `.ingest` is a control command.

regardless, and specifically regarding the [`.ingest inline` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-inline) - its input (`[field1, field2, field3, timeField]` in your example) is parsed according to the format specified (e.g. `csv` in your example). you can't use references to variables or parameters there.

Comment: Thank you.  I was afraid that might be the case.  I thought that the fact that the method executeMgmt() had a version that took query parameters suggested that they might work, as well as this analogous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75804558/how-to-ingest-using-set-or-append-with-let-statement